# Ubuntu 16.10 Postgresql ver 9.6 error 5432

Tags: 16.10, postgresql

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Even did changes to pg_hba.conf file and postgres.conf but no luck and when i checked the status using

```
netstat -ntl

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 10.0.3.1:53             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.42.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17603         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::17500                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

I got this, any idea what should i be doing?
Thank you

Comment: Is this a fresh install?

Comment: yeah complete fresh install

Comment: run this `ps auxw | grep post`. Does it return any thing?

Comment: Please delete this file `sudo rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`, and try again

Comment: bharat   22030  0.0  0.0  14208   928 pts/4    S+   20:46   0:00 grep --color=auto post

Comment: rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid': No such file or directory

Comment: Did you run it as root?

Comment: find with: `sudo find / -name .s.PGSQL.5432 -ls`

Comment: Also try this: `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`

Comment: yeah i also ran it as root but its the same and find gave me this

Comment: find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’:  Permission denied

Comment: i did restart but it's still the same

Comment: look at the options [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573204/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-mac-os-x)

Comment: Look for any error messages in `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log`

Comment: '2017-02-24 18:30:51.143 IST [17802] FATAL:  private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key" has group or world access
2017-02-24 18:30:51.143 IST [17802] DETAIL:  File must have permissions u=rw (0600) or less if owned by the database user, or permissions u=rw,g=r (0640) or less if owned by root.
2017-02-24 18:30:51.143 IST [17802] LOG:  database system is shut down
2017-02-24 18:34:32.066 IST [18203] FATAL:  private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key" has group or world access' Errror log file

Comment: this helped me     https://gist.github.com/GabLeRoux/0c60f9be0c28b6b41f64cb55474b0ccb

Answer (score 0):

This was the error  FATAL: private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key" has group or world access

Solved it with the help of this https://gist.github.com/GabLeRoux/0c60f9be0c28b6b41f64cb55474b0ccb

## Fixed ownership and mode

```
sudo chown root:ssl-cert  /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
sudo chmod 740 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

## now postgresql starts! (and install command doesn't fail anymore)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```